# jwplayer load is not working in mac safari

Tags: jwplayer

```
  var channel = '27';
  var ss_no = '2';

  jQuery('.local-tv #whats-on a').click(function() {
  channel = jQuery(this).attr('channel');
  ss_no =  jQuery(this).attr('ss-no');
});

  jQuery('.local-tv .video-option input:radio').click(function() {
  var bit_rate = jQuery(this).val();
  jwplayer('my-video' + channel).load([
    { file: 'http://ss' + ss_no + '.mylive.org:xxxx/live-channels/ngrp:ch' + channel + '_max' + bit_rate + '/jwplayer.smil' },
    { file: 'http://ss' + ss_no + '.mylive.org:xxxx/live-channels/ngrp:ch' + channel + '_max' + bit_rate + '/playlist.m3u8' }
   ]);
});
```

I'm using this code to load different bit rates on clicking radio buttons.I'm getting expected result in all except MAC/ios Safari. Seems like jwplayer('my-video' + channel).load is not working in Mac safari. It's not changing the bit rates on clicking radio button.It's working in window Machine.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this is running?

Comment: Sorry I can not. It's NON-DISCLOSURE AGREEMENT

Comment: Can you email us? We would be happy to sign something to be able to help you out. - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/